# Extract unique id's and find minimum value of another variable

Tags: sas

My data is structured as this: 
id  age 
034 5 
034 6 
034 8 
034 10 
035 3 
035 4 
035 7 
035 8 
...

I want to know the smallest age for every id. So the desired data look like this: 
id age starting age
034 5 5 
034 6 5 
034 8 5 
034 10 5 
035 3 3 
035 4 3 
035 7 3 
035 8 3 
...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE OUT AS SELECT *, MIN(AGE) AS StartingAge FROM IN GROUP BY ID;
QUIT;
```